# KeyError: 0 in CustomDataGenerator class I created

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

The error looks like this and occurs after successful run of the model for some part of the first epoch:

```
Epoch 1/50
937/938 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0089 - accuracy: 0.9913
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 0
```

My custom data generator looks as follows:

```
class CustomDataGenerator(ks.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, dataframe, x_col, y_col, img_h, img_w, batch_size):
        self.dataframe = dataframe
        self.x_col = x_col
        self.y_col = y_col
        self.img_h = img_h
        self.img_w = img_w
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(self.dataframe.shape[0] / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        X = np.empty(shape=(self.batch_size, self.img_w, self.img_h, 3), dtype='float32')
        Y = np.empty(shape=(self.batch_size, self.img_w, self.img_h, 1), dtype='float32')

        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            img_path = self.dataframe[self.x_col][index * self.batch_size + i]
            img = cv.imread(img_path)
            img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img_np = np.array(img, dtype='float32')
            img_np = img_np.reshape(-1, self.img_h, self.img_w, 3)
            img_np = img_np / 255.

            mask_path = self.dataframe[self.y_col][index * self.batch_size + i]
            mask = cv.imread(mask_path, 0)
            mask_np = np.array(mask, dtype='float32')
            mask_np = mask_np.reshape(-1, self.img_h, self.img_w, 1)
            mask_np = mask_np / 255.

            X[i, :, :, :] = img_np
            Y[i, :, :, :] = mask_np

        return X, Y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.dataframe = self.dataframe.sample(frac=1)
        self.dataframe.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

size = 16
train_gen = CustomDataGenerator(dataframe=train_df, x_col='Images', y_col='Masks', img_h=128, img_w=128, batch_size=size)
val_gen = CustomDataGenerator(dataframe=val_df, x_col='Images', y_col='Masks', img_h=128, img_w=128, batch_size=size)
test_gen = CustomDataGenerator(dataframe=test_df, x_col='Images', y_col='Masks', img_h=128, img_w=128, batch_size=size)
```

The dataframe consists of 2 columns; one containing input images and another containing output masks. The dataset can be found here:
https://www.kaggle.com/hngngn/portrait-segmentation-128x128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KeyError might have occurred because 0 does not exist in the index.

For integer-location based indexing of a data frame use `.iloc`

```
img_path = self.dataframe[self.x_col].iloc[index * self.batch_size + i]
mask_path = self.dataframe[self.y_col].iloc[index * self.batch_size + i]
```